# When is the dirac delta function taken as 1 and when it is taken as infinity

Tags: dirac-delta

I understand that the dirac delta function basically describes a pulse of area one, if the pulse is very narrow, the height will be infinity. However, Im confused because sometimes, people consider the dirac delta function as being one at t=0 (AKA the unit impulse function) rather than infinity, so when is it considered to be one rather than infinity?

P.S. In MATLAB the dirac delta function is infinity at t=0

Comment: They are probably referring to the dirac measure, which places a mass of $1$ at the singleton $0$.

Comment: Don't confuse the Dirac Delta with the Kronecker Delta https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta .  The Dirac delta is used for continuous time; the Kronecker delta for discrete time.

Comment: I know the difference between the two, what Im talking about is continuous time, sometimes they take the dirac delta as one and sometimes as infinity.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that given some metric $d(x,y)$ then $\frac{d(x,y)}{d(x,y)+1}$ is also a metric with $\infty = 1$.

Comment: The Dirac delta function, $\delta(t)$, has no meaning by itself, but is rather defined as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t) \mathrm{d}t = 1$. As Andy Walls pointed out, this is different from the Kronecker Delta function that is used in Digital signal processing which is defined as $\delta(n) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{rl}
      1 & \text{if } n = 0 \\
      0 & \text{if } n \neq 0
    \end{array} \right. $

Comment: The convention $\delta(0)=1$ is used in some books about math for engineers. Just ignore them. The correct intuition is indeed that the "value" at zero is infinite and not 1.

Comment: Thats where I get confused, Im an engineer and the books I read sometimes take 1 for the magnitude of the dirac delta.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the "value" of the delta "function" is infinite at $0$ and the "area under it" is $1$.  I am not aware of any time we take the value to be $1$.  The unit impulse refers to the total impulse delivered, which is the area under the force-time curve.

Comment: So say, if we take the derivative of the unit step function, then we get a dirac delta with a magnitud of 1 at zero?

Comment: Yes, that is true.  You just have to remember that the magnitude of a delta is not the value at $0$ but the integral across $0$.